# How to prevent paragraph rewrapping on numbers after setting fo+=n

Tags: vim

I have text like this:

```
asd skjdlaskjdkl jakljasd jaskdl kalsdj lkjasdl jaksldj lkajd lkasjd lkjasd
jasldj aslkdja ssadk j jksaj djasd aksj dskjd kaj kj  kj kj sdf asd 
2003.  aasdasdd asd asd asdkasdlkj alksdj lkadjk ljadslkj klajsdkljas 
       jaslkd  askdj kasjd lkjasdl kjadsj
```

I have added the "*n*" flag to *formatoptions* so vim can rewrap lists automatically during writing. But it has a drawback. If there is a number within the paragraph and it is placed at the beginning of a line due to the line width, vim treats it as an ordered list's item. I thought it should notice trailing spaces of all the lines before and treat the whole text as one paragraph.

Is there anything I can do to have the list feature enabled and correct paragraph rewrapping at the same time?

Comment: I don't think this is really something any computer program that doesn't try some sort of language processing to understand the semantics can do. How exactly is Vim to know that your number doesn't start a list?

Comment: As I have written - a leading space at the end of the previous line. Vim uses this [style](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table) to determine paragraph extents. See the "w" option.

Comment: Ah. You mean "trailing" space, then. And no, that can't tell Vim what you want. What if the list is in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: You're right - trailing. I don't know what I was thinking about during writing. I thought that it could be a convention that two text parts around the list would be two separate paragraphs. In particular first paragraph would end with a line without trailing spaces.